# Prove $L^2$-norm of eigenfunctions $(u_1,u_2)_{L^2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Regarding this finding $u:[0,1] \rightarrow \textbf{C}$ and  $\lambda \in \textbf{C}$ question:

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u''(x)=\lambda u(x) & x\in(0,1)\\ 
u|_{x=0} =0& \\ 
u'|_{x=1} =0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

$1.$ Prove that every eigenvalue $\lambda$  must be real.

$2.$ Let $u_1,u_2$ be two eigenfunctions of two eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$, prove the $L^2$-norm:$(u_1,u_2)_{L^2}=0$. Where $L^2$-norm is defined as $\phi(x):|\phi(x)|^2 \equiv \int |\phi(x)|^2dx$.

I am confused by this question, the first equation seems like an eigenvalue problem of $\partial_x^2$. But I don't know how to start. Do I need to find a relationship between the $L^2$-norm and the solution of the set of differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\bar u(x)u''(x)\ dx= \lambda\int^1_0 |u(x)|^2\ dx
\end{align}
then by integration by parts we have
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\bar u(x)u''(x)\ dx = \bar u(x)u'(x)\big|^1_0-\int^1_0 |u'(x)|^2\ dx=-\int^1_0 |u'(x)|^2\ dx.
\end{align}
Hence we have that
\begin{align}
\lambda = -\frac{\int |u'(x)|^2\ dx}{\int |u(x)|^2\ dx}
\end{align}
which is real.

Suppose $u_1$ and $u_2$ have corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ where $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Then it follows
\begin{align}
(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)\int^1_0 \bar u_1(x) u_2(x)\ dx= \int^1_0 (\lambda_1\bar u_1 u_2-\bar u_1\lambda_2u_2)\ dx= \int^1_0\bar u_1''u_2-\bar u_1u_2''\ dx= 0. 
\end{align}
Since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, the $(u_1, u_2)_2 =0$.